# What about site-specific post notices?

Tags: feature-request, post-notices

Now that we have site-specific custom close reasons, it got me thinking: why not make post notices customizable to each site as well? It's already [known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172574/56541) that the existing "citation needed" and "current event" post notices were primarily developed for use on Skeptics; sure, they are useful for some other sites, but not everywhere. Many other sites probably have their own particular use cases for text to be added as a post notice. In particular, I'm thinking of this [proposed book recommendation banner](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/124) on Physics.

I imagine this could be done with a UI partially similar to the custom close reasons, and perhaps the implementation could be partially similar as well (which would make it easier). What do people think - is this possible, and useful enough to justify the work on the part of SE devs?

Comment: This would help [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186087/a-better-insufficient-explanation-post-notice), too -- for most sites (science sites, at least), the current post notice is pretty useless.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is already possible - just not by mods or normal users.

If you need one, just post a [feature-request] on your meta site with the proposed wording and why you think you need it.

However, please keep in mind: **these are *not* canned comments.** They require a moderator to add them, and a moderator to remove them, they can't be replied to or edited to suit the specific nature of a given post. They are, at least in a sense, *a public badge of shame* - so think good and hard about whether or not public shaming is *really* what you want to be going for.

Comment: The notice would be used in [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698/2751) context, so it should certainly not be a public badge of shame ... Is there another feature that could serve the purpose and which could be used by non-moderators?

Comment: Does the availability of custom post notices extend to those generated from locks? (On Maths we frequently have users who post questions from CodeChef or what not while the contest is on-going.)

Comment: Yes, per-site locks are an option, @Willie (with the exception of Historical Significance locks which are special). Throw up a feature-request on meta.math with suggested wording + usage scenarios.