# Moderator Notices should be more Flexible/Prominent

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderators, post-notices

This question arises from the following Meta post on Code Review:

[Should I cast a VLQ flag on an answer that has a moderator notice on it?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/should-i-cast-a-vlq-flag-on-an-answer-that-has-a-moderator-notice-on-it)

Two of the questions I posed there, were:

> 2. Should the "Moderator Notice" include some indication that this answer is considered a VLQ, but due to the OP indicating that the answer solved his issue, the answer is not to be deleted or otherwise canned?
> 3. Should the "Moderator Notice" include the text, "Moderator Notice", to make the intentions of the mod more apparent?

It was then noted to me, in an answer:

> > Should the "Moderator Notice" include some indication that this answer is considered a VLQ, but due to the OP indicating that the answer solved his issue, the answer is not to be deleted or otherwise canned?
>
> This would best be addressed in a separate feature request (although there may have already been one on Meta SE). Moderators are only given canned post notices and cannot make custom ones.
>
> > Should the "Moderator Notice" include the text, "Moderator Notice", to make the intentions of the mod more apparent?
>
> See the above answer.

Why is this the case? Is the only way for mods to leave "custom" notices to directly edit a question? If so, why?

I feel it would be **very** beneficial to **all** the communities to be able to provide custom moderator notices, or to leave some text near the moderator notice indicating such. As it stands now, it's not apparently obvious what the intention of the moderator notices are. For example, if we take the exact, direct text of that notice:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

It's very unclear *how the community should respond* to it. Should the community continue flagging it? Should the community assume it's been dealt with? Should they downvote and let the bots take care of cleanup? As it stands, the moderator notice itself is nothing more than a bit of information to the author, *but the author is not the only person who may see the question/answer.*

If I am misunderstanding/misrepresenting things, please let me know. All of this information is acquired directly from our mods over at Code Review. I am not (nor ever have been) a mod, so I don't intend to understand the entire concept, but this particular feature (or lack thereof) has an impact on the community.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191981) is at the very least strongly related.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Though that is **very** true, this is more about making the mod notices **much** more prominent, or allowing them to create custom notices.

Comment: I think Shog9's answer in the other question handles the "allowing [mods] to create custom notices" part of your question quite fully. Post notices aren't just comments, but are "badges of shame" that should be tied to the standards of the site in question. SE can add different post notices for mods to add when appropriate, but mods cannot (and should not, IMHO) just be able to come up with them on the fly.

Comment: @ArthurFischer The problem with the "public badge of shame" idea is that **everyone** can see it, and **everyone** interprets it differently. If moderation notices are to be used like that, there needs to be an indication that it **is** a moderator not, and that it **has** been handled. We wouldn't want to make SO modify **all** the Moderator Notice templates to have the same header in them so that everyone can see it is a Moderators Note, or would we?

Comment: I haven't really touched the "visibility" portion of your question, just the customization part. I do agree that it would be better if there was a greater indication that these post notices are special (not just misplaced blockquotes). I'm not certain if beginning them with "**Moderator Notice**" is the right move. True, they can only be added by moderators, but, again, they should be indicating _community_ standards. By focusing too much on moderators, this facet might be lost. I also don't have an alternative in mind.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Ah, my mistake. Indeed that is the majority of my intention with this. (I skimmed your `part of your question quite fully` statement, that's my mistake.) Though, yes, my suggestion *may not* be the right move. It may be more appropriate to have some other *thing* done, but what I am not sure.